# Instance method not found (return type defaults to id)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am taking a warning from Xcode. Here is the code

```
 DeviceList *dList = (DeviceList* )[[User thisUser] devices];
 [dList getListId];
```

The warning states that instance method -getListId is not found. However the method exists in my source code

```
- (NSString*) getListId
{
    T
    if ( ... != nil)
    {
        return ...;
    }
    else
    {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is when I am calling the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your DeviceList.h , make sure you have

```
@interface DeviceList : Parent
- (NSString*) getListId;
..
..
@end
```

the warning occurs when your method is not declared in your header file and you try to call it outside your (self) class.

Answer (score 8):

have you added a declaration for this method in the .h file, and if so, have you imported the .h into the file you are trying to call this method?

this error is basically the compiler saying it can't find the method declaration, so it doesn't know what to expect the return type to be.

Comment: This solved it for me. I'd done `@class DeviceList;` in the header file, but not `#import "DeviceList.h"` in the implementation.